# How do you make a footer with links using CSS?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

So I'm having a problem which I can not find on the internet on exactly what I want.
I want to create a footer, like you see on all profesional websites, with the links, copyright stuff etc. Like the one we have right below us by stackoverflow.
I thought maybe to create it like my nav bar (see below), but that did not seem to work out for me.
How I want the footer: a thin bar (not to thin), with your basic links that are required (privacy policy, site map etc), a piece of text underneath for something like copyright 2016 or something like that and of course, I would like it to stay at the bottom of the page, which I think i've done.
Hopefully you understand what I require.

Thanks in advance

```css
html {
  background: url(http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Veix-Goodbye-New-York-Color-1200.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #2a70d9;
}
.content {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
}
.content p {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #6cf;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyleSheet.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentLogo">
      </div>
      <p>blah blah</p>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="footerLinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Legal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright © 2016</p>
      </div>
    </footer>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to use `position: absolute;`, as this will only give you a hard time. Keep it in the flow of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have managed to figure how to get what I want.
I basically started to research again how the whole `display:` stuff works to get a better understanding.
What I did was:
firstly create 3 divs (footer, footer links and copyright). With these 3 divs, I created borders around them with different colours for each div so I could see how each div changes after I mess about with the `display:` stuff. After finally getting the layout how I wanted with the right margin and padding. I had to research about the positioning the footer to stick to the bottom. I did it with `position: absolute;` used `bottom:0;` to push it down and used left and right 0 because the width of the footer went very small as I added `position: absolute;`, the left and right 0 corrected it for me. 
And done, that's how I done it.

See my solution:

```css
nav {
 height: 40px;
 background: black;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 width: 400px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #2a70d9;
}
.content {
 width: 800px;
 display: block;
}
.content img {
 max-width: 800px;
 height: auto;
}
.contentLogo{
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
 background: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.35);
 margin: auto;
}
.content p {
 text-align: center;
}

footer {
 background: #333333;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}
.footerLinks {
   text-align: center;
}
.footerLinks ul {
 padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.footerLinks li {
 display: inline;
}
.footerLinks a {
 color: #d9d9d9;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.copyright {
    text-align: center;
}

.copyright p {
 margin: 0;
 color: #b3b3b3;
 font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyleSheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<nav> 
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>


<footer>
 <div class="footerLinks">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="copyright">
  <p>Copyright 2016</p>
    </div>
</footer>


</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute;` from footer

```
.footerLinks ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footerLinks ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footerLinks {
    float: right;
}

.copyright {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I did what you wrote. Adding those CSS code allowed the links to lay side by side. However, removing the position: absolute; doesn't make the footer stay at the bottom, so I left that in. Also, how would I get the copyright section below the links and how do I centre them both?

Comment: Replace it with  `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this covers the issue

```css
html {
  background: url(http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Veix-Goodbye-New-York-Color-1200.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #2a70d9;
}
.content {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
}
.content p {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #6cf;
  background: red;
}
.footer ul{
  display: inline-block;
  }
.footerLinks ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footerLinks {
    float: right;
}

.copyright {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyleSheet.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentLogo">
      </div>
      <p>blah blah</p>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="footerLinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Legal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright © 2016</p>
      </div>
    </footer>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you centre both parts and have the copyright section under the links?

Comment: in that case, remove the float option and use a <br> and align them in center

Answer (score -1):

Removed styles from footer list, text-decoration from links and changed footer height. Also float left the list items and add some margins. It's not perfect but you can adjust it to your needs and preferences.

```css
html {
  background: url(http://www.newyorker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Veix-Goodbye-New-York-Color-1200.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #2a70d9;
}
.content {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
}
.content p {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #6cf;
  background: red;
}
footer .footerLinks ul{
  list-style-type: none;  
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
footer .footerLinks ul li{  
   float: left;
}
footer .footerLinks ul li a{ 
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyleSheet.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentLogo">
      </div>
      <p>blah blah</p>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="footerLinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Legal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Site Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright © 2016</p>
      </div>
    </footer>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Leaving a comment explaining the reason when down-voting is optional but it really is highly appreciated by the person that wrote the answer ;-)

Comment: It shouldn't be optional